# Dependencies not loading or partially loading

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5, ucma

I am trying to work with the MS Lync UCMA 4.0 sdk and just switched to using Visual Studio 2012 (becuase .NET 4.5 Framework is required). I can't figure out what is going on here, I've set the Target CPU to x64 and the Target Framework to .Net Framework 4.5 because I was getting the error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'SIPEPS, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Now that I've made these changes I get the below error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Could not load file or assembly 'Azure' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Azure' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = CREATIVE\kielhowell
LOG: DisplayName = Azure
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Azure | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Visual Studio Projects/TPL/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Visual Studio Projects\TPL\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Visual Studio Projects\TPL\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/kielhowell/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/186577b4/cde0def/Azure.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/kielhowell/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/186577b4/cde0def/Azure/Azure.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Visual Studio Projects/TPL/bin/Azure.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.


Stack Trace: 


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +258
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Azure' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +456



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as well, and iv tried the solutions listed here http://blog.greenl.ee/2012/08/21/error-sipeps-dll-ucma-4-0/ without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a very similar problem. I found the problem was that it couldn't find the dependency, and I was able to find out which one by using a dependency walker. 
[Link](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

You can open your .exe here, and it'll point out what you're missing in your project. For me it was the Microsoft C++ redist.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after  I copied my test code from my local machine to the trusted application server. I had to remove the Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration dll reference from the project and browsed it in the application server and re-linked it.